# Form inside Owl Carousel version 1&2

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am building a simple form inside an Owl Carousel but I can't get it to work on their version 2.

The problem is when the user click inside the input type on the second version the console log gives an error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

on the first version everything works fine. [Here is a fiddle for v1](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ryangus/w7hn3oem/) I was just wondering if somebody can take a look, I tried using **mouseDrag:false** but it doesn't do the trick.

[And here is the link for version 2](http://grupomesm.com/cindy/owl-exp/) and the code goes like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel({
        items:1,
        mouseDrag:false
    });
    // Go to the next item
    $('.customNextBtn').click(function () {
        owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is over 3 years old, but I came across the same issue. It took me hours to find a solution, so I want to share it with anyone who might be interested.

I don't know what exactly causes the error, but I figured that the error is thrown whenever the `focusout` event is triggered. Unfortunately, preventing `focusout` from bubbling didn't solve my problem.

After browsing the project's issues on GitHub, I came across [this article](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/581) where user with nickname "ghost" suggests a solution. The problem can be avoided by disabling `onclick` and `onchange` events of the input.

This code worked for me:

```
$("#controls").on('click change', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

where #controls is a `<div>` wrapper around all my form controls

Comment: Yep this was long time ago, even the examples no longer work, I stopped using owl carousel some time ago and moved to [siema] https://github.com/pawelgrzybek/siema and [vue.js] https://vuejs.org/ , anyways, I will take your word for it and accept the answer so someone else can benefit for it, thanks for the answer.